# JQuery select/Zoom/Copy/paste/crop image plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, image

I need to copy multiple selected areas from multiple images, paste them on another div to build a new image ,crop it. And finally save it on server.

To achieve that I'm looking for a JQuery plugin that can perform select/Zoom/Copy/paste/crop on an image.

I already looked over the internet I found only some plugins like JCrop, but they can perform only crop on one image with no zoom...

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [jwindowcrop plugin](http://www.tmatthew.net/jwindowcrop)

Answer (score 0):

With [Iviewer](http://www.jqueryscript.net/rotator/jQuery-Plugin-for-Image-Zoom-Rotation-Plugin-iviewer.html) jquery plugin you can do the extra work you need zoom and rotate images.

Iviewer is a jQuery UI based jQuery plugin that allows you to zoom in/out, rotate and move images in area by the mouse on your web page.

[DEMO site here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-for-Image-Zoom-Rotation-Plugin-iviewer/test/)